# Image url in Css file under stylesheets under public Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I am working with Rails 2.3.5 and I have images in public/images/ which are added into css file named as custom.css

```
#cssmenu ul {
  background: url(nav-bg.png) repeat-x 0px 4px;
  height: 69px;
}
```

How can i make this read the image which in inside public/images ?
I have tried this but it did not work

```
#cssmenu ul {
  background: url(<%= asset_path '/images/nav-bg.png' %>) repeat-x 0px 4px;
  height: 69px;
}
```

also this does not work

```
#cssmenu ul {
      background: url(<%= asset_path 'nav-bg.png' %>) repeat-x 0px 4px;
      height: 69px;
    }
```

Comment: With the asset path, you shouldn't need the `/images/` before your file name, right?

Comment: its not working also , and i have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both examples are correct:

```
#cssmenu ul {
  background: url(../images/nav-bg.png) repeat-x 0px 4px;
  height: 69px;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  background: url(/images/nav-bg.png) repeat-x 0px 4px;
  height: 69px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the image_path helper?

background: url(image_path('nav-bg.png'));

Answer (score 0):

For using this <%= asset_path 'nav-bg.png' %> you will have to add .erb after file.css and it should look like yourfile.css.erb